# Laravel search from multi select dropdown

Tags: laravel, forms, eloquent, dropdown

I am trying to create a search filter using dropdown selections. The code only shows results when all dropdowns (make and model) are selected. But it should work even single dropdown (either make or model)is selected. At the moment, if I select a single dropdown, the result page shows "No Matching Data found". this is what I have done -

**Controller**

```
class CarFrontController extends Controller
{   
    public function index_classiccars(Request $request)
    {
        $filterMakes = DB::table('cars')->select('make')->distinct()->get()->pluck('make');
        $filterModels = DB::table('cars')->select('model')->distinct()->get()->pluck('model');
        $classiccar = Car::query();

        if ($request->has('make')) {
            $classiccar->where('make', $request->make);
        }
        if ($request->has('model')) {
            $classiccar->where('model', $request->model);
        }
        return view(
            'layouts.frontend.cars.classiccars_index',
            [
                'filterMakes' => $filterMakes, 'filterModels' => $filterModels,
                'classiccars' => $classiccar->get()
            ]
        );
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->all();
        return view('layouts.frontend.cars.classiccars_index');
    }
   }
```

**data blade**

```
@forelse ($classiccars as $car)
                    <div class="row">        
                        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-pad">
                            <div class="car-thumbnail">
                                <a href="car-details.html" class="car-img">   
                                    <div class="price-box">
                                        <span>£{{ $car->price }}</span>
                                    </div>
                                @php $i=1; @endphp
                                @foreach ($car->join_caralbum as $image)
                                    @if ($i>0)
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{asset($image->image_location)}}" alt="car" height="225px" >
                                 
                                    @endif     
                            @php $i--; @endphp
                   
                        @endforeach   
                                </a>
                                <div class="carbox-overlap-wrapper">
                                    <div class="overlap-box">
                                        <div class="overlap-btns-area">
                                            <a class="overlap-btn" href="{{ url('car_show/'.$car->id) }}">
                                                <i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-pad align-self-center">
                            <div class="detail">
                                <h3 class="title">
                                    <a href="car-details.html">{{ $car->make }}</a>
                                </h3>
                                <ul class="custom-list">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">{{ $car->model }}</a> /
                                    </li>
                                    ......

                                </ul>
                                <ul class="facilities-list clearfix">
                                    .....
                                    .....
                                    ....
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                @empty 
                No matching data found
        @endforelse
```

**filter blade**

```
{!! Form::open(['action'=>'CarFrontController@index_classiccars','method'=>'GET']) !!}
                    <select class="form-control" name="make" id="make">
                        <option> Make(All)</option>
                        @foreach ($filterMakes as $make)
                            <option value="{{ $make }}">{{ $make }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select><br>
                    <select class="form-control" name="model" id="model">
                        <option> Model(All)</option>
                        @foreach ($filterModels as $model)
                            <option value="{{ $model }}">{{ $model }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select><br>
                    
                    {{ Form::submit('Update Search',['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) }}
```

Comment: Change `<option> Model(All)</option>` to `<option value=""> Model(All)</option>` and then change `if ($request->has('model'))` to `if ($request->filled('model'))`

Comment: yes. it works now. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Your query results empty because even if you don't select any of your options, you actually do. If options don't have a value, the value is the text you give it to the option.

In your case, if you select just a model, actually you are selected 'Make(All)' option too. You can see this simply by putting `dd($request->all())` on your `index_classiccars` method.

For checking selects, you can give empty value to first(default) option and control it with `request()->filled('input')`.